# How assign value to a namespace object variable if it is get it inside a jquery on click definition

Tags: jquery, javascript-namespaces

I want to know how can I save a value inside a jquery bind when this is inside a namespace.

```
var obj = obj || (obj ={ 
    valuetosave:-1,
    init:function(){
        $("some selector").on("click",function(){
            tmpval = I get some value here
            how can asign 'tmpval' to obj.valuetosave if I can't use this because 
            is in the jquery scope
        })
    }
})
```

I know that neither the title or my little description is not much useful, I hope the little example can speak about my issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to refer to the current instance of `obj` then u should use *this* keyword.
for example

```
var obj = obj || ({ 
  valuetosave:-1,
  init:function(){

    var self = this;  // preserver your global instance in a variable
      $("#mybutton").on("click",function(){               
          var tmpval = 'I get some value here'
          // here `this` refers to  the function event instance , not obj instance
          // So i am using self (which is global instance variable)
          self.valuetosave = tmpval;
          alert(self.valuetosave);
      });
  }
});
```

Let me know if u need more help, checkout [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/madhuvana/BtyMp/) link.